# How to share a capsule revision ID with another person with different samsung accounts?

Tags: samsung-mobile, bixby, bixbystudio

I am trying to share a capsule that I have built with another person who isn't a collaborator of the capsule on Bixby Developer Center, nor is my Samsung account connected to their device. When they try to test the capsule, it shows this error message.

> You don't have access to this capsule revision ID.

I am looking for ways to let them run my capsule without sharing my Bixby Developer account or adding them as a collaborator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature to protect client privacy. In order to execute revision override in IDE or on-device testing on mobile, the current login user must be a member of the team.capsule listed in the DEV center.

There are multiple ways to fix this:

1. add the person as a member. Details in https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/managing-caps.managing-your-team. Please make sure add the person to capsule. Invite to the team is not enough.
   OR
2. publish and get approved to marketplace. There would be no need for revision ID. All targeted region users will be able to add and use your capsule.
   OR
3. Send capsule code to the other developer and he/she can test the capsule in IDE after changing the team.capsule namespace. However, this would not work if any config or secret involved.

I would personally suggest #1 is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will be implementing that! I have been building a Bixby capsule revolving around COVID-19 but I realized that it won't be approved by the marketplace.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately it is a very sensitive topic at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

In order to add a collaborator you must first invite them to your namespace/domain, and once the person accepts invitation you can add that person to a specific capsule in that domain.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

You must add the user as a collaborator for them to be able to use your capsule.

Comment: Thank you for your response!